# TypeORM: How to query Many to Many along with one to one/many

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, relational-database, typeorm

I'm building REST API based on Wordpress Database schema! using typeORM with Express.

My problem is I couldn't set the right relations! Based on the image below I'm trying to connect `wp_terms` with `wp_posts` tables! for having categories and tags with every post

1. I know that `wp_terms` linked to `wp_term_taxonomy` by One to One relationship, not inverses. ( Note some sites say that it's one to many relationship so please correct me if I'm wrong based on the image below )
2. Then `wp_term_taxonomy` table has many to many relationships with `wp_posts` table

## My problem: That I get the wp_term_taxonomy with my posts instead of terms itself.

## So my data results look that way: ( the term_id is missing )

```
[  
   {  
      ID:12,
      // ...etc

      // IAM GETTING THE TAXONOMY TYPE NOT THE TERMS IT SELF 
      //( term_id on the wp_term_taxonomy table not here either )
      categories:[  
         {  
            termTaxonomyId:3,
            taxonomy:"category",
            description:"",
            parent:"0"
         },
         {  
            termTaxonomyId:6,
            taxonomy:"category",
            description:"",
            parent:"0"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So that my entities:

**`wp_posts` entity**

```
@Entity({ name: 'wp_posts', synchronize: false })
export class WpPostsModel {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public ID?: number;

    @Column()
    public post_date?: string;

    @Column()
    public post_date_gmt?: string;

    @Column()
    public post_content?: string;

    @Column()
    public post_title?: string;

    ...etc

    @ManyToMany(() => WpTermTaxonomyModel)
    @JoinTable({
        name: 'wp_term_relationships',
        joinColumn: {
            name: 'object_id',
            referencedColumnName: 'ID'
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
            name: 'term_taxonomy_id',
            referencedColumnName: 'termTaxonomyId'
        }
    })
    public categories?: WpTermTaxonomyModel[];

}
```

**`wp_term_taxonomy` entity**

```
@Entity({ name: 'wp_term_taxonomy', synchronize: false })
export class WpTermTaxonomyModel {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'term_taxonomy_id' })
    public termTaxonomyId?: number;

    @OneToOne(() => WpTermsModel)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'term_id' })
    public term?: WpTermsModel;

    @Column()
    public taxonomy?: string;

    @Column()
    public description?: string;

    @Column()
    public parent?: number;

}
```

**`wp_terms` entity**

```
@Entity({ name: 'wp_terms', synchronize: false })
export class WpTermsModel {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public term_id?: number;

    @Column()
    public name?: string;

    @Column()
    public slug?: string;

    @Column()
    public term_group?: number;
}
```

**Posts Controller**

```
private getAllPosts = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
    const posts = await this.postRepository.find({ relations: ['categories'], where: { post_type: 'post', post_status: 'publish' } });
    response.send(posts);
}
```

## The Wordpress DB Schema

[image]

Comment: Very interesting stuff ... did you get it working?